# How do i refresh a directory file list in python

Tags: python, import, refresh, urllib

I made a piece of code that is meant to download a single file python library, and import it to automate tasks. The library is one made by me and stores on github. whenever i import it after downloading it errors out and says that library doesn't exist or it can't import. It would be best if it was single file.
My github is FranticCodeStudent1

```py
import urllib.request
import os
import time

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://franticcodestudent1.github.io/dlrepo/KeyLite.py", "KeyLite.py")
time.sleep(1)
import KeyLite
KeyLite.SendKey(KeyLite.VK_RETURN)
```

Comment: Why not make a proper library on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) instead?

Comment: Your code is not throwing an error in my end, you can use the same. For more details kindly share the error log.